# Cache PIP packages in dockerfile

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pip, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to setup docker for my python project, Which uses virtual environment and has defined some dependencies in `requirements.txt`.

I have setup `docker-compose` too which uses `Dockerfile` to build my project image using command `docker-compose up --build`

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
 FROM python:3.5  
MAINTAINER ****  

ADD . /core-proejct
WORKDIR /core-project
RUN pip3 install virtualenv
RUN . /bin/activate
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

So, every time when I am trying to build the image its installing all pip modules from `requirements.txt`.

Is there anyway by which I can cache the pip modules and use the cached version while building image.

Comment: This may also be wrong:

ADD . /core-proejct

'proejct' is misspelled, but not consistently misspelled.

Answer (score 2):

First things first, the `FROM ubuntu:16.04` in your dockerfile is redundant as a single image can only have one upstream.

The simple way to solve your problem is move your `pip` commands to before you add your project, so that changing your project doesn't invalidate the whole cache.

Lastly, you really don't need to use virtualenv in a container, otherwise you [may be doing something wrong](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#each-container-should-have-only-one-concern).

Eg:

```
FROM python:3.5

# MAINTAINER is deprecated. Use LABEL instead.
LABEL maintainer "your info here"

WORKDIR /core-project

ADD ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Add everything else now.
ADD . .
```

Comment: `ADD . .` will run into less problems

Comment: I've heard mixed opinions about using a virtualenv inside of a container.  Though it's undisputed that each container should ideally have a single purpose, there are plenty of people that choose to further separate app dependencies from OS dependencies using a virtualenv, even in a docker container.

Comment: Please note that this does not work when using COPY instead of ADD

Comment: @VME My observations don't confirm this. `COPY` works rather well and is preferable because it has a narrower use-case (no URL sources, no archive unpacking).